# Adding labels to xypic

Tags: xy-pic

How would I add labels to the following xypic?

```
\xymatrix{
  1 \ar@<-.5ex>[r] \ar@<.5ex>[r] & 2.
}
```

I would like to add a `\alpha_1` above the top arrow and a `\alpha_2` below the bottom arrow.

Comment: `\ar@<-.5ex>[r]_{\alpha_2} \ar@<.5ex>[r]^{\alpha_1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    ,all
    %,cmtip
    ]{xypic}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{%
\ar@<-.5ex>[r]_{\alpha_2} \ar@<.5ex>[r]^{\alpha_1} & 2
}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\arrow[shift left=.7ex]{r}{\alpha_1} \arrow[shift right=.7ex]{r}[below]{\alpha_2}& 2
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]